# Given a value in an table of values in Excel, how to return the corresponding value from the first column/row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data-set:

[image: Dataset Snippet]

Given a number that occurs only once in the data range B2:E5, I would like to use a formula that returns the corresponding date value. The date values are given in the first column (A2:A5). I would also like to be able to return the corresponding hour value using a similar formula. Note, it is not necessary to return the hour and the date for a given value using the same formula.

**Example:** In the image of the data-set above – given the number 5, I would like to return the corresponding date. In this case, the formula would return the date value 03/01/2013. Similarly, I would also like to be able to return the "hour 3", given the same initial value.

Maybe the answer to this question is quite straight forward, but as of yet I have had no luck in figuring it out. Some things that I have tried, but to no avail, are the following: VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP, LOOKUP, a combination of INDEX+MATCH, and a combination of INDEX+MATCH+MATCH.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Number to Find is unique, you can use this:

For the date in Column 1

```
=INDEX(Table1[Column1],MAX((NumToFind=Table1 )*ROW(Table1 ))-1)
```

For the hour in the Headers fields:

```
=INDEX(Table1[#Headers],1,MAX((NumToFind=Table1)*COLUMN(Table1)))
```

The above formulas are array formulas and must be confirmed by holding down <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The `-1` in the first formula is to compensate for the fact that the table starts in Row 1, with the data starting in Row 2, and the formula determines the absolute row number; if it starts other than in `A1`, different compensating values will be required.

[image]

Comment: Nice work Ron, very creative. About the `-1` in the formula for the date if the Table starts at row 11 what it would be the replacement value for `-1`? And also does the second formula need a compensating value as well?

Comment: @EEM  Table1 refers to the Data Area of the table (starts at 2nd Row/1st Column) The correction factor will be the difference between the first row or column of data, and row/column 1. So no correction for column since the data area starts in column 1; but if you move the table to start in a different column than one, then yes, you would need the correction.

Comment: Suggest then to update your answer accordingly (i.e. row 2 instead of row 1)